# What is the difference between database migrations and transactions while unit testing in Lumen?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, lumen

Per the Lumen 5.3 documentation:

> Using Migrations
>
> One option is to rollback the database after each test and migrate it
>   before the next test. Lumen provides a simple DatabaseMigrations trait
>   that will automatically handle this for you. Simply use the trait on
>   your test class:
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> use Laravel\Lumen\Testing\DatabaseMigrations; 
> use Laravel\Lumen\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
>
> class ExampleTest extends TestCase 
> {
>     use DatabaseMigrations;
>
>     /**
>      * A basic functional test example.
>      *
>      * @return void
>      */
>     public function testBasicExample()
>     {
>         $this->get('/foo');
>     } 
> }
> ```
>
> Using Transactions
>
> Another option is to wrap every test case in a database transaction.
>   Again, Lumen provides a convenient DatabaseTransactions trait that
>   will automatically handle this:
>
> ```
> <?php
>
> use Laravel\Lumen\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
> use Laravel\Lumen\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
>
> class ExampleTest extends TestCase 
> {
>     use DatabaseTransactions;
>
>     /**
>      * A basic functional test example.
>      *
>      * @return void
>      */
>     public function testBasicExample()
>     {
>         $this->get('/foo');
>     } 
> }
> ```

As you can see the explanation text is nearly identical and the code example is the exact same with the exception of the trait usage. So it is clear to me that the difference lies completely within the way that the framework handles the tests.

What do these do differently and when would you prefer one over the other?

If one difference has to do with database driver I am using MYSQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DatabaseMigrations` migrates the database when you run the test, then rollsback the dabase when test is finished.

`DatabaseTransactions` uses transactions. Any data inserted from your database will be rolledback after the test.

The difference between the two is `DatabaseMigrations` uses migrations (migrates your database migration then rolling it back after the test) while `DatabaseTransactions` uses the transaction (data inserted from the database are rolledback)

Source: https://mattstauffer.co/blog/better-integration-testing-in-laravel-5.1-databasemigrations-databasetransactions-and-withoutmiddleware

Comment: So would an apt trade off summary be that Migrations are safer but slower and transactions are faster but technically working on live data and then trusting that the transactions will be able to be rolled back at the end?

Answer (score 0):

Transaction in SQL gives you the possibility to rollback the INSERTion, to commit the insertion you would have to explicitly do so using COMMIT.

Which gives you the ability to do the unit tests without altering the database itself.

Same goes for the migrations, but they wont give you control over every single transaction.